# Keras network fit: loss is 'nan', accuracy doesn't change

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I try to fit keras network, but in each epoch loss is 'nan' and accuracy doesn't change... I tried to change epoch, layers count, neurons count, learning rate, optimizers, I checked nan data in datasets, normalize data by different ways, but problem was not solved. Thanks for your help.

```py
np.random.seed(1337)

# example of input vector: [-1.459746, 0.2694708, ... 0.90043]
# example of output vector: [1, 0] or [0, 1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='tanh', init='normal', input_dim=503))
model.add(Dense(2, init='normal', activation='softmax'))

opt = optimizers.sgd(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1000, nb_epoch=100, verbose=1)
```

```
99804/99804 [==============================] - 5s 52us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.4938
Epoch 1/100
99804/99804 [==============================] - 5s 49us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.4938
Epoch 2/100
99804/99804 [==============================] - 5s 51us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.4938
Epoch 3/100
99804/99804 [==============================] - 5s 52us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.4938
Epoch 4/100
99804/99804 [==============================] - 5s 52us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.4938
Epoch 5/100
99804/99804 [==============================] - 5s 51us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.4938
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, problem has been found! After normalization, one nan neuron appeared in the input vector

Answer (score 0):

First convert your output to categorical, as described in [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/losses/):

> Note: when using the categorical_crossentropy loss, your targets should be in categorical format. In order to convert integer targets into categorical targets, you can use the Keras utility to_categorical:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
categorical_labels = to_categorical(int_labels, num_classes=None)
```