# Loss is always nan when training a deep learning model from tabular data

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to train a model from a dataset of about a few thousands of entries with 51 numerical features and a labeled column, Example:

> [image: Blockquote]

when training the model to predict the 3 labels (candidate, false positive, confirmed) the loss is always nan and the accuracy stabilizes very fast on a specific value.
The code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler, RobustScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from tensorflow import optimizers
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Normalization
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential, Model 


def load_dataset(data_folder_csv):
    # load the dataset as a pandas DataFrame
    data = pd.read_csv(data_folder_csv, header=0)
    # retrieve numpy array
    dataset = data.values

    # split into input (X) and output (y) variables
    X = dataset[:, :-1]
    y = dataset[:, -1]
    print(y)

    # format all fields as floats
    X = X.astype(np.float)
    # reshape the output variable to be one column (e.g. a 2D shape)
    y = y.reshape((len(y), 1))
    return X, y


# prepare input data using min/max scaler.
def prepare_inputs(X_train, X_test):
    oe = RobustScaler().fit_transform(X_train)
    X_train_enc = oe.transform(X_train)
    X_test_enc = oe.transform(X_test)
    return X_train_enc, X_test_enc


# prepare target
def prepare_targets(y_train, y_test):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    ohe = OneHotEncoder()
    le.fit(y_train)
    le.fit(y_test)
    y_train_enc = ohe.fit_transform(y_train).toarray()
    y_test_enc = ohe.fit_transform(y_test).toarray()
    return y_train_enc, y_test_enc



X, y = load_dataset("csv_ready.csv")

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)

print('Train', X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print('Test', X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

X_train_enc, X_test_enc = X_train, X_test
print('Finished preparing inputs.'

# prepare output data
y_train_enc, y_test_enc = prepare_targets(y_train, y_test)

norm_layer = Normalization()
norm_layer.adapt(X)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation="tanh", kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))

opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train_enc, epochs=20, batch_size=128, verbose=1, use_multiprocessing=True)

_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test_enc, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy * 100))
```

I tried increasing/decreasing the learning rate, changing the optimizer, lowering and increasing the number of neurons and layers, and playing with batch sizes but nothing seems to bring the model to get good results. I think I'm missing something here but can't put my finger on it.
Result example: [image]

EDIT: More lines from the csv:
[image]

EDIT2: Tried l2 regularization also and didnt did anything.

Comment: It is problem of exploding gradient. Recheck your model and loss metrics again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reasons:
Check whether your dataset have `NaN` values or not. `NaN` values can cause problem to the model while learning.

Some of the major bugs in your code:

- You are using `sigmoid` activation function instead of `softmax` for output layer having 3 neurons
- You are fitting both train and test set while using encoders which is wrong. You should `fit_transform` for your train data and only use `transform` for test sets
- Also you are using input for all layers which is wrong, Only the first layer should accept the input tensor.
- You forgot to use `prepare_inputs` function for `X_train` and `X_test`
- Your model should be fit with `X_train_enc` not `X_train`

Use this instead

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from tensorflow import optimizers
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Normalization
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential, Model 


def load_dataset(data_folder_csv):
    # load the dataset as a pandas DataFrame
    data = pd.read_csv(data_folder_csv, header=0)
    # retrieve numpy array
    dataset = data.values

    # split into input (X) and output (y) variables
    X = dataset[:, :-1]
    y = dataset[:, -1]
    print(y)

    # format all fields as floats
    X = X.astype(np.float)
    # reshape the output variable to be one column (e.g. a 2D shape)
    y = y.reshape((len(y), 1))
    return X, y

# prepare input data using min/max scaler.
def prepare_inputs(X_train, X_test):
    oe = MinMaxScaler()
    X_train_enc = oe.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test_enc = oe.transform(X_test)
    return X_train_enc, X_test_enc

# prepare target
def prepare_targets(y_train, y_test):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    ohe = OneHotEncoder()
    y_train = le.fit_transform(y_train)
    y_test = le.transform(y_test)
    y_train_enc = ohe.fit_transform(y_train).toarray()
    y_test_enc = ohe.transform(y_test).toarray()
    return y_train_enc, y_test_enc



X, y = load_dataset("csv_ready.csv")

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)

print('Train', X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print('Test', X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

#prepare_input function missing here
X_train_enc, X_test_enc = prepare_inputs(X_train, X_test)
print('Finished preparing inputs.')

# prepare output data
y_train_enc, y_test_enc = prepare_targets(y_train, y_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation="relu")) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

#opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train_enc, y_train_enc, epochs=20, batch_size=32, verbose=1, use_multiprocessing=True)

_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test_enc, y_test_enc, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy * 100))
```

Comment: I tried the following code but still getting 'nan' loss and an accuracy value of exactly 0.2444, same as before.

Comment: @Zedler can you try this code with using MinMaxScaler instead? Check my updated answer

Comment: still the same exactly same result

Comment: @Zedler do your dataset have NaN values after normalization? It might be one of the reasons. Check whether all your training and testing data have NaN or not. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55431690/keras-network-fit-loss-is-nan-accuracy-doesnt-change

Comment: That did the trick, some values had Nan and had to normalize them, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You want to change your model definition to this:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=X_train.shape[1:], activation="tanh", kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

You only need to define the input shape for the first layer, Keras will automatically determine the proper shape for the subsequent layers.  You leave out the batch size when defining the input_shape, which is the first dimension, hence `input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]`.

A `sigmoid` activation will actually work (because the output will vary between 0 and 1), but what you really want is a `softmax` activation (which makes sure all the outputs sum to 1, which is what probability dictates -- the probability that *something* happened is 100%, not the 120% that `sigmoid` could end up giving you).

Also, you're not using your `LabelEncoder` anywhere.  I think what you mean to do is this:

```
def prepare_targets(y_train, y_test):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    ohe = OneHotEncoder()

    # teach the label encoder our labels
    le.fit(y_train)

    # turn our strings into integers
    y_train_transformed = le.transform(y_train)
    y_test_transformed = le.transform(y_test)

    # turn our integers into one-hot-encoded arrays
    y_train_enc = ohe.fit_transform(y_train_transformed).toarray()
    y_test_enc = ohe.transform(y_test_transformed).toarray()
    return y_train_enc, y_test_enc
```

Comment: still giving me the same 'nan' and accuracy values but yeah, softmax is def the way to go.

Comment: Can you add the first few lines of `data_ready.csv` to your question?  Until I see the input data, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: edited the question with more lines from the csv :]